# Why execution getting frozen after launching website in given browsers on different nodes in selenium grid?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

As I am new to automation testing and would like to understand the issue as mentioned below. Your help will help me to execute suites seamlessly on selenium grid for cross browser testing.

Issue:

I am executing tests on IE and Chrome on different nodes. When I am executing the test cases mentioned in testng.xml file for grid, browsers get open with website and gets logged in to application as well but nothing happens further. It looks like execution is frozen and driver doesn't quite browsers.
Similarly, I run test cases locally on same system for one browser, it works means execution doesn't freeze. It moves further after login.

Is it related to driver instance issue? or any other thing doing it wrongly.

Used:
Hub and 2 nodes in which 1 node is created on Hub only.

Hub - Node 1 : IE browser
Node 2 : Chrome browser

Below is code :

```
package managers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import enums.EnvironmentType;

public class VMSBaseDriver {
    public WebDriver driver;
//  private static DriverType driverType;
    private static EnvironmentType environmentType;
    private static final String CHROME_DRIVER_PROPERTY = "webdriver.chrome.driver";
    private static final String IE_DRIVER_PROPERTY = "webdriver.ie.driver";

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Parameters("browserName")

    @BeforeClass

    public void initialize(String browser) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        environmentType = FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getEnvironment();
//      driverType = FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getBrowser();

        switch (environmentType) {
        case LOCAL:
            System.out.println("(In Local) Selected environment from config :: " + environmentType);
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                System.setProperty(CHROME_DRIVER_PROPERTY,
                        FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getDriverPath() + "/chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("internetexplorer")) {

                System.setProperty(IE_DRIVER_PROPERTY,
                        FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getDriverPath() + "/IEDriverServer.exe");
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                        true);
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_USE_PRE_PROCESS_PROXY, true);
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, false);
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

            }

            if (FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getBrowserWindowSize())
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(
                    FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getImplicitlyWait(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            // driver.get(FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getApplicationUrl());
            driver.get("http://" + getIPAddress());
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            break;

        case REMOTE:
            System.out.println("(In Remote) Selected environment from config :: " + environmentType);
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

                FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
                FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

                profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
                profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
                profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 0);
                firefoxOptions.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.20.1.24:4444/wd/hub"), firefoxOptions);
            } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {

                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
                options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
                capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");

                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.20.1.24:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("internetexplorer")) {

                DesiredCapabilities iecapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                iecapabilities.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
                iecapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                        true);
                iecapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
                iecapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
                iecapabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
                iecapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
                iecapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "");
                iecapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.LOG_LEVEL, "DEBUG");

                iecapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.20.1.24:4444/wd/hub"), iecapabilities);

            }

            if (FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getBrowserWindowSize())
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(
                    FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getImplicitlyWait(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("http://" + getIPAddress());
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            break;
        }

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void TeardownTest() {

        driver.quit();

    }

    public String getIPAddress() {

        InetAddress IP = null;
        try {
            IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            // System.out.println("IP of my system is := " + IP.getHostAddress());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return IP.getHostAddress();
    }

    public By extendedLocator(String locString, String value)

    {

        return By.xpath(String.format(locString, value));

    }

}
```

TestNG.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="2" name="VMSTestSuite" parallel="tests">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="listeners.ExtentReportTestListener" />
        <!-- <listener class-name="listeners.AnnotationTransformer"/> -->
    </listeners>


    <test name="Internet Explorer execution">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="internetexplorer" />
        <classes>

            <class name="testCases.ViewsTest" />
            
        </classes>
    </test> 

    <test name="chrome execution">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome" />
        <classes>

            <class name="testCases.WebPagesTest" />
            
        </classes>
    </test>
    
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

ViewsTest.Java class

```
package testCases;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;

import managers.ExtentReportTestManager;
import managers.VMSBaseDriver;
import pageObjects.CamerasAndEncodersPage;
import pageObjects.MonitoringPage;
import pageObjects.ViewsPage;

public class ViewsTest extends VMSBaseDriver {

    public MonitoringPage monitoringPage;
    public ViewsPage viewsPage;
    CamerasAndEncodersPage camerasAndEncodersPage;
    public String[] Servers;

    @BeforeClass
    public void init() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        monitoringPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, MonitoringPage.class);
        viewsPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, ViewsPage.class);
        Servers = viewsPage.getServersList();

        driver.navigate().to("http://" + Servers[0]);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        viewsPage.SignIn();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        viewsPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockAppears();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        viewsPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockDisappears();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        viewsPage.GoToViewsPageFromLanding();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        viewsPage.GoToViewsPage();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    
    /*
     * @AfterMethod public void browserCategory(Method method) {
     * ExtentReportTestManager.startTest(method.getName()).assignCategory(((
     * RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().toUpperCase());
     * 
     * }
     */

    @Test
    public void AddNewViewTest(Method method) throws Exception {
        //logger = report.startTest("AddNewViewTest");
        ExtentReportTestManager.startTest(method.getName()).assignCategory(((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().toUpperCase());

        int viewsCount = viewsPage.GetViewsSize();
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Click on New button");
        viewsPage.ClickOnNewButton();

        String viewName = "ViewName" + viewsPage.GetRandomDigit(0, 10000);
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Input name " + viewName + " in name field");
        viewsPage.InputIntoNameField(viewName);

        String remarks = "Remarks for " + viewName;
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Input remarks " + remarks + " in remarks field");
        viewsPage.InputIntoRemarksField(remarks);

        int layoutSize = viewsPage.GetLayoutSize();
        int random = viewsPage.GetRandomDigit(0, layoutSize);
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Select layout ");
        viewsPage.ClickOnLayoutByIndex(random);

        int viewSize = viewsPage.GetLayoutViewSize();
        int resourcesSize = viewsPage.GetResourcesSize();
        int rand = viewsPage.GetRandomDigit(1, viewSize);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Drag " + rand + " resources ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rand; i++) {
            int viewIndex = viewsPage.GetRandomDigit(0, viewSize);
            int resIndex = viewsPage.GetRandomDigit(0, resourcesSize);
            String viewId = viewsPage.GetViewIDByIndex(viewIndex);
            String resourceId = viewsPage.GetResourcesIDByIndex(resIndex);
            viewsPage.DragAndDropCameraToView(resourceId, viewId);
        }

        int fullViewSize = viewsPage.GetFullViewsSize();
        int audioViewsSize = viewsPage.GetAudioViewsSize();
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Press Save button");
        viewsPage.PressSaveButton();

        String viewNameSaved = viewsPage.GetViewName();
        String viewRemarksSaved = viewsPage.GetRemarksText();
        int fullViewSizeSaved = viewsPage.GetFullViewsSize();
        int audioViewsSizeSaved = viewsPage.GetAudioViewsSize();

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that view name is equals to inputed");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(viewNameSaved, viewName);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that view remarks is equals to inputed");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(viewRemarksSaved, remarks);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that layout has " + fullViewSize + "resources");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(fullViewSizeSaved, fullViewSize);
//        Assert.assertEquals(audioViewsSizeSaved,audioViewsSize);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Refresh page ");
        viewsPage.Refresh();
        // int viewsCount = viewsPage.GetViewsSize();
        int viewsCountAfterRefresh = viewsPage.GetViewsSize();
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that new view is added ");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(viewsCountAfterRefresh, viewsCount + 1);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Click on " + viewName + " view");
        viewsPage.ClickOnViewByName(viewName);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        String viewNameRefreshed = viewsPage.GetViewName();
        String viewRemarksRefreshed = viewsPage.GetRemarksText();
        int fullViewSizeRefreshed = viewsPage.GetFullViewsSize();
        int audioViewsSizeRefreshed = viewsPage.GetAudioViewsSize();

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that view name is equals to inputed after refresh");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(viewNameRefreshed, viewName);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that view remarks is equals to inputed after refresh");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(viewRemarksRefreshed, remarks);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that layout has " + fullViewSize + "resources after refresh");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(fullViewSizeRefreshed, fullViewSize);
//        Assert.assertEquals(audioViewsSizeRefreshed,audioViewsSize);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Go to Monitoring page");
        viewsPage.GoToMonitoringPage();

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Input into filter field");
        monitoringPage.FilterField(viewName);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that new view is present in Monitoring Resources list");
        boolean viewIsExist = monitoringPage.VerifyThatResourceIsExist(viewName);
        AssertJUnit.assertTrue(viewIsExist);
    }

    

}
```

WebPageTest.Java class

```
package testCases;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;

import managers.ExtentReportTestManager;
import managers.VMSBaseDriver;
import pageObjects.MonitoringPage;
import pageObjects.WebPagesPage;

public class WebPagesTest extends VMSBaseDriver {


    public MonitoringPage monitoringPage;
    public WebPagesPage webPagesPage;
    public String[] Servers;

    /*
     * @AfterMethod public void browserCategory(Method method) {
     * ExtentReportTestManager.startTest(method.getName())
     * .assignCategory(((RemoteWebDriver)
     * driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().toUpperCase());
     * 
     * }
     */

    @BeforeClass
    public void init() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        monitoringPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, MonitoringPage.class);
        webPagesPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, WebPagesPage.class);
        Servers = webPagesPage.getServersList();
        webPagesPage.SignIn();
        webPagesPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockAppears();
        webPagesPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockDisappears();
        webPagesPage.GoToWebPagesPageFromLanding();

        /*
         * driver.navigate().to("http://" + Servers[0]); try{
         * driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); }catch(Exception a){}
         * 
         * webPagesPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockAppears();
         * webPagesPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockDisappears();
         * webPagesPage.GoToWebPagesPage();
         */
    }

    @Test
    public void AddNewWebPageTest(Method method) throws InterruptedException {
        // logger = report.startTest("AddNewWebPageTest");
        
        
        ExtentReportTestManager.startTest(method.getName())
         .assignCategory(((RemoteWebDriver)
         driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().toUpperCase());

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Click on new button");
        webPagesPage.ClickOnNewButton();

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that Save button is disabled");
        AssertJUnit.assertFalse(webPagesPage.SaveButtonIsEnabled());

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that Cancel button is enabled");
        AssertJUnit.assertTrue(webPagesPage.CancelButtonIsEnabled());
    }

    

}
```

hub.bat file-

```
java -jar C:\Users\Hub\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -hubConfig hubconfig.json
```

hubconfig.json file -

```
{
      "port": 4444,
      "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
      "servlets" : [],
      "withoutServlets": [],
      "custom": {},
      "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
      "registryClass": "org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry",
      "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
      "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
      "role": "hub",
      "debug": false,
      "browserTimeout": 0,
      "timeout": 1800
}
```

Node 1 present on HUB : IE -

IEnodewithjosnconfig.bat file

```
Java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\WebDriver\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar C:\Users\Hub\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -nodeConfig ieconfig.json
```

ieconfig.json

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
    
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 4548,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://IP Address of hub:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

NODE 2 : Chrome -

CHROMEnodewithjsonconfig.bat file

```
Java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\WebDriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe" -jar C:\Users\node_IE\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -nodeConfig chromeconfig.json
```

chromeconfig.json

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
   
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 4549,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://IP address of Hub:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

What would I be doing wrong in above code. Please help me to resolve this issue

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: Can you try adding [Parallelizable] attribute before the test definition?

Comment: Please help me with sample code